# Mongoose connection fails in NextJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I have a small demo project made with NextJS where I use server actions to read documents from MongoDB using Mongoose.

The problem is I keep getting this error in my terminal:
`MongoNotConnectedError: Client must be connected before running operations`

It happens if I navigate from one page to another quickly, i.e. before the page is done rendering.

Full project can be viewed here: https://github.com/rts-cmk-wu10/next-mongo-crud

My connect/disconnect setup:

```js
// @/lib/db
import mongoose from "mongoose"

export async function connect() {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("MongoDB Connection Error", error)
    }
}

export async function disconnect() {
    try {
        await mongoose.disconnect()
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("MongoDB disconnect error", error)
    }
}
```

My server action:

```js
// @/actions/get-people
"use server"

import Person from "@/models/person"
import { connect, disconnect } from "@/lib/db"

export default async function GetPeople() {
    try {
        await connect()
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        return []
    }

    try {
        const people = await Person.find()
        await disconnect()
        return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(people))
    } catch (error) {
        await disconnect()
        console.error(error)
        return []
    }
}
```

And finally my page:

```js
// @/app/read/page.js
import GetPeople from "@/actions/get-people"
import MainHeading from "@/components/text-components/main-heading"
import Link from "next/link"

export default async function Read() {
    const people = await GetPeople()

    return (
        <>
            <MainHeading>Read <span className="text-lg text-gray-600">(Læs)</span></MainHeading>
            <ul>
                {people?.map(person => (
                    <li key={person._id}>
                        <Link href={`/read/${person._id}`} className="hover:underline">{person.name}, {person.age}</Link>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Mongoose in NextJS you should follow this official example from NextJS team:

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";

// uncomment this if you are using typescript
// declare global {
//   var mongoose: any; // This must be a `var` and not a `let / const`
// }

const MONGODB_URI = process.env.MONGODB_URI!;

if (!MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error(
    "Please define the MONGODB_URI environment variable inside .env.local",
  );
}

let cached = global.mongoose;

if (!cached) {
  cached = global.mongoose = { conn: null, promise: null };
}

async function dbConnect() {
  if (cached.conn) {
    return cached.conn;
  }
  if (!cached.promise) {
    const opts = {
      bufferCommands: false,
    };
    cached.promise = mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI, opts).then((mongoose) => {
      return mongoose;
    });
  }
  try {
    cached.conn = await cached.promise;
  } catch (e) {
    cached.promise = null;
    throw e;
  }

  return cached.conn;
}

export default dbConnect;
```

and call the above function before every stack of operations (You don't need to close the connection):

```js
export default async function GetPeople() {
    try {
        await dbConnect()
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        return []
    }

    try {
        const people = await Person.find()
        return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(people))
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        return []
    }
}
```

You can find the source code of the example here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-mongodb-mongoose/lib/dbConnect.ts

You might also need to read this documentation from Mongoose which solves some common issues: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/nextjs.html